# the Android Studio can't find Java on my computer

Tags: java, android

My system is windows 7 x86; My java edition is 1.7.0_79;
when I type java -version in the cmd, it shows that the java is installed correctly. However, after I added the JAVA_HOME to the environment variable with the path I installed JAVA,which is "D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79", the android studio can't open with the same error that it can't find JAVA_HOME.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to google? Because that is a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set path to JDK in the project properties of Android Studio: File -> Project Structure -> SDK location -> JDK location.